# dhis2 XML import error: "failed to move to start element"

Tags: xml, import, dhis-2

I tried to import some XML data from a file I created, but I got an error message:

> failed to move to start element

What does it mean?

Comment: It means the DHIS 2 developers ought to improve their diagnostic messages.

Comment: Based on the message you provided, I would assume there was a problem parsing the xml you provided. If you could provide some more information about what you are importing (Data, metadata, etc) and/or a snippet of the actual xml you are trying to import, I could try to help you.